# Vertically center text within longtable row

Tags: vertical-alignment

I noticed the abominable chasm of empty space below all characters in my table.

[image: Avert your eyes.]

Changing the font, font size and leading did nada. Similar questions had been asked, but I didn't find the same. The 'what TjJ' is in a `p` column in a longtable, making it an `m` or `b` column (from the `array` package) does nothing visually significant. Adjusting `\addtolength\aboverulesep{}` and `\..\below..`, and `\midrule[0pt]`-ing ruins the coloring scheme, unless I'm using it wrong from the little I'd tried. In MS Paint I measured the distances to the top/bottom from the `j`, I want those two distances equal, without any extra been put in. Is that even possible?

Is any code example necessary if the abyssal void persists and pervades regardlessly? :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l p{1cm}}\hline
foo & bar \\\hline
foo & bar \\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Here is an example of the `m` column with `pag` font being the same height as the default roman when superpositioned.

[image: dddd]

The `m`,`t`,`b` column types vertically align the rest of the columns as if the they're `\multirow`-s. With the following you can test to see that most (haven't tried all) font families doesn't equal space to the `\hline`s above/below their longest ascenders/descenders.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont% select any font really
\begin{longtable}{l p{11cm}}\hline
foo & AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz and this continue to second row \\\hline 
\end{longtable}
    \vspace*{-48.8pt}
    \fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont% select any font really
    \begin{longtable}{l m{11cm}}\hline
    foo & AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz and this continue to second row \\\hline 
    \end{longtable}
        \vspace*{-48.8pt}
        \fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont% select any font really
        \begin{longtable}{l b{11cm}}\hline
        foo & AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz and this continue to second row \\\hline 
        \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What happens if you put a `\strut` in the cell? Please show us a complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which includes everything (including the packages) necessary to reproduce your issue, but *nothing* more. Take a look on how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by following that link.

Comment: you seem to be using a font with relatively small descenders without adjusting `\strut` to match but with no code shown hard to guess.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would redefining the `\strut' height fix the problem, I've never had to use one, so I'm unfamiliar, and the WikiBook isn't helpful

Comment: Your example doesn't compile and doesn't show the problem.

Comment: you have not posted any code that shows the problem so how can anyone tell you how to fix it. posting some unrelated code that does not make the posted image does not count as posting an example!

Comment: your question is _all about the font used_ but you have not said which font that is, and your example uses a different font and different text. latex needs to position the baseline such that any normal text fits in the cell, so far enough under the line above to hold a capital and far enough above the row below to hold a descender.  that means if your actual text has no descenders (like your code example `foo` then the space under the baseline isn't used)  in your image for which you provided no code there is a j with a very small descender, but perhaps other letters have longer ones.

Comment: Just testing different font families superimposed, there is no such letter whose descender extends the the bottom itself. From the top of the ascender or max capital height to the `\hline` there is a third to a half of the space from the lowest point of the lowest letters to the bottom `\hline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the spaces, you have to redefine the `\strut`.

To get an equal distance between the upper line and the highest and the lower line and the deepest character in your font, you can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array} % forgot to add array
\showboxdepth2
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont
\newcommand\changestrut{%
  \setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
    \setbox0\hbox{ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}%
    \skip0\dimexpr\baselineskip-\ht0-\dp0\relax
    \vrule height\glueexpr\ht0+.5\skip0\relax depth\glueexpr\dp0+.5\skip0\relax width0pt
  }%
}
\changestrut
\begin{longtable}{l p{11cm}}\hline
foo & AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz \\\hline 
\end{longtable}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
\changestrut
\begin{longtable}{l p{11cm}}\hline
foo & AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz \\\hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output]
The line `\setbox0\hbox{...}` can be changed to include all characters you expect to use. You can also try only including "typical" charaters. Then the characters will look more centered, but you may get problems with deep glyphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array} % forgot to add array
\showboxdepth2
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont
\newcommand\changestrut{%
  \setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
    \setbox0\hbox{ABCDE}%
    \skip0\dimexpr\baselineskip-\ht0-\dp0\relax
    \vrule height\glueexpr\ht0+.5\skip0\relax depth\glueexpr\dp0+.5\skip0\relax width0pt
  }%
}
\changestrut
\begin{longtable}{l p{11cm}}\hline
foo & AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz \\\hline 
\end{longtable}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
\changestrut
\begin{longtable}{l p{11cm}}\hline
foo & AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz \\\hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is TeX language, right? Do you learn how to redefine something, like the `\strut`, over time or is there some resource that you'd recommend?

Comment: You can read the TeXbook, but most of the time it is better to stay with the LaTeX commands.

Answer (score 2):

Different fonts have different characteristics. For instance, Computer Modern glyphs have a maximum height of 6.94444pt and maximum depth 1.94444pt, with an x-height of 4.30554pt. On the other hand, Avant Garde has maximum glyph height 7.35498pt, maximum depth 2.14998pt and x-height of 5.46999pt (I'm using the TeX Gyre project clone, Adventor).

The ratio height/depth is similar (3.57 for Computer Modern, 3.42 for Avant Garde), but the x-heights are very different.

Assume you want to typeset a whole document in Avant Garde (Adventor), you have to do at least one adjustment: you need to increase the baseline skip, because of the bigger height and depth: 12pt are not sufficient, because the total height is 9.5pt against 8.88888pt of Computer Modern. This would only leave 2.5pt between a deep glyph on one line and a high one on the next instead of more than 3pt. Let's assume we choose 13pt of baselineskip with `\linespread{1.08}` (it would actually give 12.96pt).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgadventor}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\linespread{1.08}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
what TjJ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Let's do some computations. The two rules are 12.96pt apart; the height of the T is 7.35498pt, the depth of j is 2.14998pt. The baseline is 12.96*0.7=9.072pt from the top rule, leaving about 1.72pt of white space. The baseline is 12.96pt*0.3=3.888pt from the bottom rule, leaving about 1.74pt of white space.

More interestingly, the top rule is 3.6pt from the top of the w, with just less than 0.3pt of difference in white space (0.1mm) which is negligible and makes the main part well centered in the available space.

With alternating colors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\linespread{1.08}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{black!30}{white}
\begin{tabular}{l}
what TjygJ \\
what TjygJ \\
what TjygJ \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How did I measure the parameters?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgadventor}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABC}

\the\ht0 % max height of Computer Modern glyphs

\the\dp0 % max depth of Computer Modern glyphs

\the\dimexpr1ex % x-height of Computer Modern

\sbox0{\sffamily abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABC}

\the\ht0 % max height of Adventor glyphs

\the\dp0 % max depth of Adventor glyphs

{\sffamily\expandafter}\the\dimexpr1ex % x-height of Adventor

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where from did you gather the various x-heights, max. heights and depths of the fonts? Can you measure any internally?

Comment: @vlg I added the way I got the lengths.